# Sign convention for voltage between two points on a circuit

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

[image]

I'm trying to calculate the voltage between different points denoted as, for example, Vab or Vce or Vfb. But looking at answer keys in my textbook, I'm getting the opposite sign of what makes sense to me. For example, take Vfb. Starting at f and moving in the direction of the current (cw), I drop 2V, drop another 2V, and gain 12V. I would think this means I gained 8V, so Vfb is 8V. But the correct answer is -8V. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

V<sub>fb</sub> means the potential difference at f with respect to b. Imagine a voltmeter with its red probe (+) on f and its black probe (-) at b. If you build the circuit in your schematic and do this with a voltmeter, it'll read -8 V. This is because, as you correctly reasoned, there is a lower potential at "f" than at "b."

Put another way, you treated f as "zero" and worked out the potential difference at b. Instead you should call b "zero."

Answer (score 1):

The question is using double subscript notation, \$V_{fb}\$. Using this notation we say that, "\$V_{fb}\$ is the voltage from f to b using b as the reference." To assist in remembering I use \$V_{RB}\$ where \$R\$ and \$B\$ are the red and black wires of a voltmeter.

So \$V_{fb}=-8 V\$ while \$V_{bf}=+8 V\$.

> I would think this means I gained 8V.

This is a correct statement. What you calculated starting KVL at node f is \$V_{bf}=+8 V\$

So \$V_{xy}\$ means start at node y then traverse to node x. That will be the voltage from x to y.